# Why is the accuracy of my model different on my confusion matrix than when I am training it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using a dataset of 5 classes of images with around 4000 images in training data set, and 2000 in testing dataset.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix



img_width, img_height = 512, 384

categories = ["cardboard", "glass", "metal", "paper", "plastic"]

train_data_dir = '/Users/lukasrois/ve/Train_Data'
test_data_dir = '/Users/lukasrois/ve/Test_Data'

classifier = Sequential()




if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)


classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape = (64,64,3), activation= 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(.1))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))



classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape = (32,32,3), activation= 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(.1))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))



classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])



train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, target_size=(64,64),
                                              batch_size=10, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_data_dir, target_size=(64,64),
                                              batch_size=10, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True)


nb_train_samples = len(train_set)
nb_validation_samples = len(test_set)

train_labels = train_set.classes


hist = classifier.fit_generator(train_set, steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=50,
                                validation_data=test_set, shuffle=True)


plt.plot(hist.history['acc'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()


y_pred = classifier.predict_generator(test_set)
y_pred = np.rint(y_pred)

y_true = test_set.classes

predict_class = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
predict_class = predict_class.tolist()

print(confusion_matrix(y_true, predict_class))

sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_true, predict_class), square=True, annot=True, cmap='Blues', fmt='d', cbar=False)
```

When I am training my model this is the output after it was finished training:

```
Epoch 50/50
426/426 [==============================] - 336s 788ms/step - loss: 0.0405 - acc: 0.9881 - val_loss: 0.5690 - val_acc: 0.8882
```

And my confusion matrix looks like this:

```
[[ 17  38  15  35  16]
 [ 80 280  80 173 143]
 [ 45 129  55  76  49]
 [ 54 187  56 121  76]
 [ 43 140  50  85  87]]
```

However, if I add up all the correct features on the confusion matrix and divide it by the total of incorrect features I get 560/1570= 0.36. So why is the accuracy different?

**EDIT**
I have changed the method of how I create a confusion matrix. I made my own function which does not rely on the test_set, Like this:

```
def config_confusion_matrix():
    actual_values = []
    predicted_values = []
    for i in range(50):
        c = categories.index(random.choice(categories))
        r = categories[c]
        path = "/Users/lukasrois/ve/Test_Data/"+r+"/"
        random_filename = random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))])
        new_path = "/Users/lukasrois/ve/Test_Data/"+r+"/"+random_filename
        result = cast_predict(new_path)
        predicted_values.append(result)
        actual_values.append(c)

    return (actual_values, predicted_values)
```

Confusion matrix:

```
array([[ 6,  0,  0,  0,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  5,  0,  3],
       [ 0,  0,  8,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  1, 10,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  4,  5,  0,  0]])
```

Current accuracy:

```
>>> classifier.evaluate_generator(test_set)
[0.28701336261618293, 0.9285955914520505]
```

However, my confusion matrix still does not reflect the same accuracy when training. Why?

Comment: Because that is not how you should be computing any metric with a generator, you cannot use test_set.classes as it is not in the same order as samples from the generator.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the matching classes for my confusion matrix?